# Codeigniter error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have updated my codeigniter version from 2.2.4 step by step to 3.0.6 and I get an error:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect()

Filename: path-to-project\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php

Line Number: 135

Backtrace:

File: path-to-project\application\controllers\Main.php
Line: 10
Function: __construct

File: path-to-project\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

I have just replaced my index.php file and system directory with the new one and made some changes in my application according to tutorial.

and this is the Main controller:

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('main_model');
    }
}
```

What causes the problem?!

And [this is the link](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html?highlight=upgrade) of the tutorial.

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated from php 5 and removed from php 7. switch to mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: In addition, please submit a link to that tutorial.

Comment: Now, the problem comes with the codeigniter or I am using the deprecated mysql in my code?

Comment: Use this in your `config/database.php`: `'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',` (change `mysql` to `mysqli`).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thanks to **Anant**

I come to a conclusion:

I completely changed my old database.php file in config folder with the new one:

From:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = '';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

To:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => '',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

And the error is gone!

Comment: Your `dbdriver` config value is empty, you should use `$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';`

Comment: Hi, i already apply your solution but the error still appearing. any other solution?

Comment: Thanks, you save my day.

Comment: where can i find the application/config/database.php ???

Answer (score 105):

[Deprecated features in PHP 5.5.x](https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/php-docs-7-en/migration55.deprecated.html):

> The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions.

You're using the deprecated `mysql` dbdriver. Locate the `config/database.php` file and change `dbdriver` to use `mysqli` :

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

Comment: Yes, thanks it works but have some problem, I am  configering old project version of ci is 2.4.0 but after creating db and import the backup, also changed in config->database.php 'mysql' to 'mysqli'. Finally fatal error is gone but the data of heder is comming perfect but on the place of body content shoing xammp page. Don't know why. Any suggestion if you have .

Answer (score 8):

go to application/config/database.php
and just change `mysql` to `mysqli`

like 
this was before:

```
 $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

this was after solution:

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

---

i just change mysql to mysqli. that's it

my error was

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_pconnect() in
>   E:\manish_data\software\xampp\htdocs\ci2\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php:92
>   Stack trace: #0
>   E:\manish_data\software\xampp\htdocs\ci2\system\database\DB_driver.php(116):
>   CI_DB_mysql_driver->db_pconnect() #1
>   E:\manish_data\software\xampp\htdocs\ci2\system\database\DB.php(149):
>   CI_DB_driver->initialize() #2
>   E:\manish_data\software\xampp\htdocs\ci2\system\core\Loader.php(347):
>   DB(Array, NULL) #3
>   E:\manish_data\software\xampp\htdocs\ci2\application\models\usermodel.php(20):
>   CI_Loader->database() #4
>   E:\manish_data\software\xampp\htdocs\ci2\application\controllers\users.php(15): UserModel->getUsers() #5
>   E:\manish_data\software\xampp\htdocs\ci2\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(360):
>   Users->index() #6
>   E:\manish_data\software\xampp\htdocs\ci2\index.php(202):
>   require_once('E:\manish_data\...') #7 {main} thrown in
>   E:\manish_data\software\xampp\htdocs\ci2\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php
>   on line 92

Comment: LOL dude, you basically just copied my answer.. but without even explaining why it's necessary to update the `dbdriver`

Comment: Hello @Sfili_81 ,Please find out difference between mysql and mysqli so different database support different driver to connect with the application. When you download xampp by default xampp have mysqli and you can connect to mysql or any other db with different drivers where it will be present . You are not only who code .

Answer (score 0):

If this error happened when you're hosting the website, make sure to set the correct PHP Version (the one your CI use).