# How to resolve a 'Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect()' error in PHP while running the index file through NetBeans 8.2?

Tags: java, php, mysql, netbeans-8

When I am running my PHP index file through NetBeans 8.2 then I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_pconnect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Property\Connections\PMS.php:9
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Property\register.php(1):
>   require_once() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Property\Connections\PMS.php on line 9

Could you please advise me on possible solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40358357/296555. The `mysql` API doen't exist anymore. Move over to `mysqli` or `PDO` - https://phpdelusions.net/pdo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter error: Call to undefined function mysql\_pconnect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822462/codeigniter-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-pconnect)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to [include the package mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250356/how-to-install-mysqli) (the package you should be using for mysql) in your php libraries.

You can also check that you have the package by seeing if it is listed in `phpinfo();`.