# When am running a codeigniter project in local host, it shows error

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, codeigniter-3, mamp

[image: error showing image]

The problem is am running this project in MAMP php version 8.0.3, and the codeIgniter version is 3, I think it will not support in php version 8.0.3. What is the solution of this problem?
This is my localhost url :http://localhost:8888/mansions/

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost:8888';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'root';
$db['default']['database'] = 'mansions_new_live';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

This is the database configuration details. Is there any solution for this?

I want to run this project in mamp server, its already working in windows server. but it is not working in mamp php version 8.0.3

[image: when using mysqli db driver]

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822462/codeigniter-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-pconnect and make sure `mysqli` extention is installed and enabled.

Comment: how can i install mysqli extension

Comment: I don't know how to install it on mac, but `mysqli` should be bunlded with MAMP, so check if it's enabled or not, (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6285262/6934036).

Comment: what version of codeigniter are you using? according to CI doc, it looks CI 3 is compatible with php 8 from version 3.1.12

Comment: This is CI version 2

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql driver is deprecated. To use `mysqli` driver, add this parameter to your config file located in `config/database.php`.

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

Comment: I tried this also. but it shows error. A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346

Comment: try to change $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE; to $db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;. Also, you can try to change hostname to 127.0.0.1:8888.

Comment: $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE; to $db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE; this also i tried

Comment: i tried to change the hostname also, but it dosen't works and showing the same error.

Comment: Thats interesting. Try to set $db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;.

Comment: no changes. same error.

Comment: I think no one can find a solution to my problem.